# Why is my setter method producing a bad access error

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

Bad access means that i am trying to access memory that doesn't exists I have tried and tried to allocate memory for this class, but have failed everywhere. I do not know where the error is actual coming from. It only tells me that my setter method is when the program crashes. In the setFName() method is where the error occurs. But in the main method is where it actually occurrs.
nurse.hpp

```
#ifndef Nurse_hpp
#define Nurse_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class nurse{
private:
    string firstName;
public:
    nurse() {
        firstName = "jim";
    }
    string getFName() {return firstName;}
    void setFName(string fName) {firstName = fName;} // Thread 1: bad access 0x0
};

#endif /* Nurse_hpp */
```

here is where the error is actually happening
main.cpp

```
#include <cstdint>  // ::std::uint64_t type
#include <cstddef> // ::std::size_t type
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "nurseHolder.hpp"
using namespace std;

nurseHolder *l = new nurseHolder();

int main() {


 return 0;
}
```

and finally here is the class that is causing the issue
nurseHolder.hpp

```
#ifndef Nurses_hpp
#define Nurses_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Nurse.cpp"
using namespace std;

class nurseHolder{
private:
    int nurse_cnt;
    int nurse_cap;
    vector<nurse> nurse_list;
public:


    nurseHolder()  {
    nurse_cnt = 0;
    nurse_cap = 10;
    for(int i= 0; i < 11; i++){
        nurse_list[i].setFName("na");
      }
    }
    vector<nurse> &getNurseList() { return nurse_list;}

};

#endif /* Nurses_hpp */
```

I tried to make this compact as possible sorry if its a lot of code.

here is what I changed to make the code work:

```
nurseHolder()  {
        nurse_cnt = 0;
        nurse_cap = 10;
        for(int i= 0; i < 11; i++){
            nurse l;
            nurse_list.pushback(l);
          }
        }
```

Is this a correct way to do this?

Comment: Your vector `nurse_list` has size 0.

Comment: how do I add a size? @tkausl

Comment: You add to the vector using its `push_back` method. When you use the array access syntax, like in `nurse_list[i]`, you are accessing an element that supposedly already exists.

Comment: @DevinTripp Use the appropriate [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), [`resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize), or [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)

Comment: `vector.push_back(element)` adds elements to vector, currently it is empty

Comment: I can see `nurse_cap` variable. I believe, it is meant for vector capacity. You can set the initial capacity of your nurse vector to `nurse_cap`.

Comment: `<stdio.h>` is called `<cstdio>` and `<stdlib.h>` is called `<cstdlib>` in C++. Also: Everytime you use a raw owning pointer a kitty dies.

Comment: what's a raw owning pointer? @Swordfish

Comment: @DevinTripp `nurseHolder *l = new nurseHolder();` for example. `l` owns the memory allocated. If you copy the pointer `l` it is no longer clear who is responsible for realeasing the memory allocated. Use smart pointers like `std::shared_ptr<>` and `std::unique_ptr<>` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your vector `nurse_list`  has size 0. So you cannot use `[]` operator to set names.
There are two ways you can correct this:

1. Set an initial size to the vector and use `[]` to set names.
2. Use `push_back` to add elements to the vector.

First method.

```
nurse_list.resize(noOfTotalNurses). 
nurse_list[i].setFName("name");
```

Second method.

```
nurse tNurse; //local nurse object
tNurse.setFName("name");
nurse_list.push_back(tNurse);
```

Comment: i did this. Tell me if its ok.

Comment: You have to set the name for the `nurse l` object using `setFName`.